# Java -Spring 4.1.0 - Webapp Beans Loading Twice

Tags: java, spring

In my spring based Java project, the startup tasks for my project seem to be getting loaded twice.
Would anyone have any idea based on the information at the following gist why this is happening for me?
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bf5b01686f03dadc57c7

The output in the class WebappStartupTasks is getting printed twice to the console.
Its probably something to do with how I have my xml files setup but I cant seem to find the reason why this is happening

Thank you
Damien

Comment: And why shouldn't it… You have 2 context loaded and events from the child propagate to the parent. So you will receive 2 events, one from the `ContextLoaderListener` and one from the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Also see my comments on your gist, there is room for improvement and easier code/configuration.

Comment: perfect, thank you for these comments  - very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.

You can tell which context the event is for using:  `event.getApplicationContext()` and fire only when it's for the `ContextLoaderListener` or the `DispaterServlet` depending on your requirement.

If your only concern is that the functionality runs once and only once then I think your best approach is to maintain the state of the initialisation independently.  I've done this in the past using a simple static flag:

```
if(!SchedulerContextListener.INITIALISED) {
    initialise();
    SchedulerContextListener.INITIALISED = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys - I thought I was doing something wrong but when ye mention it like this it makes perfect sense

Comment: Actually sorry StuPointerException - is there a specific property on the applicationContext I can check on or should I check this based on the display name or applicationName of the context?

Comment: I've edited my answer.  The problem probably isn't 'which context caused the event to fire', since the outcome is the same!  You just want your code to run once.